# Por que estão aparecendo estes erros no Razor ao compilar o projeto?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Alterações feitas por mim

```
@model Pessoa; // já tentei module3.Models.Pessoa e todas as variacoes    possiveis
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Pessoa";
}

h2> @ViewData["Title"]</h2>
<p>Name: @model.Nome </p>


<p>Id:@model.Id</p>
```

---

```
namespace module3.Models
{
    public class Pessoa
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

```
public IActionResult Pessoa()
{
    var pessoa = new Pessoa{Id=12,Nome="2324"};
    return View(); 
}
```

---

```
/home/developer/Documentos/dotnet/module3/Views/Home/Pessoa.cshtml(1,6): error RZ1011: The 'page' directives value(s) must be separated by whitespace. [/home/developer/Documentos/dotnet/module3/module3.csproj]
/home/developer/Documentos/dotnet/module3/Views/Home/Pessoa.cshtml(6,14): error RZ2005:The 'model` directive must appear at the start of the line. [/home/developer/Documentos/dotnet/module3/module3.csproj]
/home/developer/Documentos/dotnet/module3/Views/Home/Pessoa.cshtml(6,19): error RZ1011:The 'model' directives value(s) must be separated by whitespace. [/home/developer/Documentos/dotnet/module3/module3.csproj]
/home/developer/Documentos/dotnet/module3/Views/Home/Pessoa.cshtml(7,11): error RZ2005:The 'model` directive must appear at the start of the line. [/home/developer/Documentos/dotnet/module3/module3.csproj]
/home/developer/Documentos/dotnet/module3/Views/Home/Pessoa.cshtml(7,10): error RZ2001:The 'model' directive may only occur once per document. [/home   /developer/Documentos/dotnet/module3/module3.csproj]
/home/developer/Documentos/dotnet/module3/Views/Home/Pessoa.cshtml(7,16): error RZ1011:The 'model' directives value(s) must be separated by whitespace.          [/home/developer/Documentos/dotnet/module3/module3.csproj]
   0 Warning(s)
   6 Error(s)
```

Comment: Parece que está faltando colocar logo na primeira linha um `@page`

Comment: desculpe a leiguice, mas ai eu removo o @model ou ponho antes, o curso que estou vendo parece estar desatualizado :/ pq esta no asp.net core 1.0

Comment: Tente colocar primeiro é o `@page`, depois o resto como está. Aproveitando que você está aprendendo, dê uma olhada no *ASP Net Razor Pages*. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yyBijyCI5Sk